# Couldn't understand the actual use of "-F<pat>" switch in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

## from the doc:

*`-Fpattern       split() pattern for autosplit (-a)`*

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -an -F -e 'puts $_;puts $_.split; puts $F[3] if /^a/'
a fdrvo hhl vgtl bbnn                             
a fdrvo hhl vgtl bbnn
a
fdrvo
hhl
vgtl
bbnn
vgtl

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -an -e 'puts $_;puts $_.split; puts $F[3] if /^a/'
aaas kgkb hv njjj jlh
aaas kgkb hv njjj jlh
aaas
kgkb
hv
njjj
jlh
njjj
```

As the output is same for both the code thus couldn't understand the actual use of `-F<pat>` in ruby. Can anyone help me here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -a -n -Fp -e 'puts $_;puts $F[3]'
apf drvoph hlpvg tlpbbpnn
apf drvoph hlpvg tlpbbpnn
vg tl

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -a -n -e 'puts $_;puts $F[3]'
apf drvoph hlpvg tlpbbpnn
apf drvoph hlpvg tlpbbpnn
tlpbbpnn
```

The pattern after `-F` ('p' in this case) is used as the separator instead of a blank space.

Comment: It would be good to see also if you include `puts $_.split`.Otherwise its OK... I got my mistake. :) `+1` to you.